# Is it possible to create custom relationships in Laravel models?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a relationship which is neither One-To-One nor One-To-Many and I was wondering if it's possible to express a custom relationship in Laravel/Eloquent models.

Essentially I have products which belong to a single category, but multiple products can belong to the same category. The `products` table stores the `category_id`. This obviously isn't One-To-One as categories are reused and Laravel would require a `product_id` foreign key on the `categories` table. It is closer to a One-To-Many, which is limited to a single item, but I'd prefer having to avoid making an additional `category_product` table to define a single relationship. I suspect this is a Many-To-One relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, it's a One-To-Many relationship where a `category` **hasMany** products and a `product` **belongsTo** to a single `category`:

1. *Essentially I have products which belong to a single category.* **equivalent to**: a `product` belongsTo to a single `category`.
2. Multiple products can belong to the same category. **equivalent to**: a `category` hasMany products.

Therefore, the following relationships will work:

```
class Product extends Model
{

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

And:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: You are right it is obvious, I was working too late! I was thinking about the relationship the wrong way around hence `Many-To-One` as if the product owned the category, when of course it is the other way round - hence the inverse of `One-To-Many`.